# Clebsch-Gordan coefficients - sum simplification

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, representation-theory

I have the following sum to compute:
$$\sum\limits_{\mu=-\lambda}^\lambda
\left(
C^{l+\epsilon/2,m}_{l,m-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}
C^{l'+\epsilon'/2,m-\mu}_{l',m-\mu-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}}
C^{l,m-\frac{1}{2}}_{l',m-\mu-\frac{1}{2};\lambda,\mu}+
C^{l+\epsilon/2,m}_{l,m+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}}
C^{l'+\epsilon'/2,m-\mu}_{l',m-\mu+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}}
C^{l,m+\frac{1}{2}}_{l',m-\mu+\frac{1}{2};\lambda,\mu}
\right)^2$$
Where $l,l',\lambda$ are set and are integers greater or equal 0. The numbers $\epsilon,\epsilon'$ are set set take values of $\pm1$.

The result does not depend on $m$ (I checked numerically and I have a physical reason behind that), so I'm pretty sure there must exist a simplification, so that there is no $m$ in the expression. I looked up identitites and recurrence relations in Varschalovich but with no success.

My notation of CG coefficients follows that of Varschalovich, i.e.
$$C^{j,m}_{j1,m1;j2,m2}=
\langle jm|(|j1m1\rangle\otimes|j2m2\rangle).$$

Comment: This is a bit of a huge expression to tackle without more of an idea of what's going on behind the scenes. It would help a lot if you can explain where the expression comes from and what it's meant to represent, and what physical grounds you have to suspect an independence w.r.t. $m$. Are you sure there isn't a Wigner-Eckart argument to be had on other footholds for this expression?